# Downloadable link to a strapi media file

Tags: next.js, content-management-system, strapi

I have a scenario where I need to download a file from ***Strapi*** media library when a button is clicked on my client side *(Next.js App)*. I have been looking for a *downloadable link* for the file which I upload to the ***Strapi*** media library.

Is there any way I can get the *downloadable link* to the files in the ***Strapi*** media library. Please help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

In your endpoint you have to do: **GET** `/api/articles?populate=*`

See docs: https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/api/rest/populate-select

Answer (score 0):

**/api/upload**

```
GET /api/upload/files Get a list of files
GET /api/upload/files/:id Get a specific file
```

Need to set permissions for find and fineOne in settings -> Users & Permissions plugin -> Role -> Upload 
You could retrieve the url of the uploaded file:

[image]